# Solution to get JCrop to support image zooming

Tags: javascript, zooming, crop, jcrop

I have been searching all of the net but I can not seem to find a simple opensource plugin which essentially provides a basic image cropping tool.

Here is the deal... I am essentially looking for exactly what "jcrop" provides example: http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=live_crop

however with the added ability of just being able to zoom in/out of the image.

The simplest tool which demonstrates what I am looking for is:
http://kroppr.rborn.info

as you can see its just like jcrop but this one lets you zoom into the image and move the image around so you can get the crop area you want.

Is there ANY opensource solution out there or does anyone happen to have the skill to integrate this quick hack?

Comment: Saw this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487546/jquery-how-to-add-to-jcrop-zoom-feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is free opensource solution. It is a exact copy of kropper (functionality-wise, not sure otherwise). http://www.gastonrobledo.com.ar/cropzoom/index.html

Edit: Above link is broken , as the developer has changed his domain name to http://www.cropzoom.com.ar/

New Link of this guys: https://github.com/gastonrobledo/cropzoom

Comment: The link does not seem to work... Do you still have those files?

Comment: Seems to be very late answer, but may be helpful for others as well. This guy has new domain here: http://www.cropzoom.com.ar/